# Receive message from Python (kivy)

Tags: php, database

I've got a MySQL server set up and my particular setup needs to use PHP as the middleman between my Python program (kivy app) and the MySQL server.

**I do know** how to send a message from my app to the server.
**I also know** how to PHP my way through MySQL (thanks to http://www.freewebmasterhelp.com/tutorials/phpmysql/1).
**What I don't know is how PHP can receive the message (from any number of clients) and use the data inside.**

So lets assume I've just sent out "Thomas, 29, England" from Python to PHP. How do I get PHP to use this data?

Comment: Question: whats the reason you cannot use python to access your database. http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb.html 
Providing some more information may help people solve your question.

Comment: exactly how can we answer this? you've explained NOTHING about how you'd like your apps to communicate. http? https? sockets? hire an army of cheap slaves to transcript messages from one computer to another? infinite monkeys banging out all possible messages?

Comment: Steve: The server I'm renting has MySQL with PHPadmin preinstalled, it is a website server. The server limits access to MySQL by making you insert IP's manually (so you can never go public). It does not support installing any extra programs on it. I don't mind getting another server, but right now I'm looking for the easiest solution.

Comment: Marc: I know nothing about sockets or similar. All I know is I need mobile apps (written in python) to connect to my MySQL and I need a middle man between them just because the query has to be made from a single IP. If I was incredibly brilliant at this I wouldn't be asking.

Comment: Steve: to clarify the IP thing: only manually added IPs are allowed to access the database.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to put PHP into an HTTP server, like Apache or Nginx, than use some python web client, like [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/), to send an HTTP GET or HTTP POST to the PHP server, that could get the data via [$_GET](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_get.asp) or [$_POST](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_post.asp) variables. Than do whatever you need from this PHP server.

(lets assume that you want Python and PHP to talk over a TCP/IP network, local or not)